# Azure function proxy returns error 500

Tags: azure-functions, azure-api-apps, azure-function-app-proxy

Currently I am having Azure API app located in UK but I would like to create a Proxy in HK for my users in china to access the servers without much performance impact in connecting the DB server that's allocated in EU.

I just setting up the proxy functionality on Azure function, which is located in East Asia. Unfortunately, I kept getting error code 500 with the api request though postman.

How can I trace the error which is causing error code 500?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding to Hamid's Answer,

When you add the header *"Proxy-Trace-Enabled: true"* to the request, you will see a Response Header *"Proxy-Trace-Location"* giving a link to access the trace log for that request. The link also gives the Trace ID for the particular call.

Comment: Thank you. I responded on the above answer. I'm now testing it with browser to call the URL of function app, which I hope it will proxy to another website.

Comment: I suspect there is something incorrect in proxy definition. Is it possible for you to share your proxies.json or a screen shot of your proxy definition in the portal?

Comment: Please see the info in proxies.json
`{
    "proxies": {
        "proxy-home-eu": {
            "matchCondition": {
                "route": "/{*path}",
                "methods": [
                    "GET"
                ]
            },
            "backendUri": "https://sails-app.azurewebsites.net/{*path}"
        }
    }
}`

Comment: please fix the proxies.json as below `{
  "proxies": {
    "proxy-home-eu": {
      "matchCondition": {
        "route": "/{*path}",
        "methods": [
          "GET"
        ]
      },
      "backendUri": "https://sails-app.azurewebsites.net/{path}"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: got it. Unfortunately, it only works with the home page, not the following path.
Example: http://funcviva.azurewebsites.net is working but http://funcviva.azurewebsites.net/blog is not working

Comment: Looks like there is a redirect from sails-app.azurewebsites.net/blog to sails-app.azurewebsites.net/blog/ that is causing this failure. This needs a fix in proxies. I will update this thread once the fix is in. Thank

Comment: This is fixed and live now!

Answer (score 4):

The trace logs will be in D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Proxies folder.

Also if you need more detailed logs you can add this header to your request:

Proxy-Trace-Enabled: true

And it will create a file under D:\home\LogFiles\Application\Proxies\DetailedTrace folder for each request.

If you can't figure out the cause of 500, please let us know the function app name and the time in UTC and we can investigate.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late response. I'm trying to make it simple. To proxy to a website from browser.

Comment: The function app name = funcviva and u can check 01:33 @02 April